# Rim Joist Insulation with Backer Rod

Tags: basement-insulation

I want to take a semi-permanent approach in insulation for my rim joists as I’ve heard DIY spray foam may not pass inspection and it would be a lot of work to remove once sprayed and cured. I’m thinking using foam board cut very tight and using backer rod around the edges to further seal/insulate. Is this a good idea? Maybe reduced R value? Yes I’m expecting this to take more time and fair amount of backer rod. Next step would be come back in with bat insulation ocer the XPS.

Comment: What's your goal? Why don't simple fiberglass batts suffice?

Comment: I’m no expert but concerned the batts will trap moisture and not provide enough seal/thermal block as compared to a friction fit foam board with backer rod